# Why don't mined blocks show up in my inventory on my Spigot server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-spigot

I have a simple Spigot server installed on a Rasperry Pi. So far so good. I log in and it works, until I realize that when I mine a block it never reaches my inventory. No dropped block. **Nothing is left behind, except a void which used to be occupied.** I have seen others with this problem, is it just a quick permissions/settings file fix, or is it intended. It is not on adventure, it says survival on the console window when starting up. It's really weird. I have tried mining on other Spigot servers powered by Pis, and it didn't work, yet the server admin put up a bunch of signs.

What do I have to do to configure the server to work correctly? Am I accidentally using a "unstable/uncompleted" build? (It says 1.6.4) Is this not a feature yet? Is there a mod that will fix this? Did the original admin of other servers use creative?

Comment: Can you list your permissions?

Comment: @Batophobia I know where that file is but I haven't touched it besides taking a quick peek inside to see if there was anything. There wasn't, and the council widow of my server says that the permissions.yml or whatever is blank but it will ignore it. I've tried looking for what should be in there, but I couldn't find anything so I figured that it should default and act like a normal MC server. It doesn't say anything on the chat window either.

Comment: When joining a server, you need to elevate your permissions, which van be done with the `op username` command.  So for me it would be `op batophobia`.  You should be able to run this command from the server.

Comment: @tell Batophobia Yes, I know about that, but you don't need to be a op to mine blocks, or I don't think that you would need to. I have visited plenty of servers that I didn't get OPed and I could mine a block and it would be placed in my inventory. Would this matter? I'm not using the `/give` command *which* you would need op for *that*, but also I haven't ever used Spigot.

Comment: Only ops can mine blocks within a certain distance of the spawn point.

Comment: @Batophobia Forgot about that. :P But that doesn't explain that I can *mine* them. Lag? When I logged off and on while I was in a little void (not *the* void, :P) and when I logged on, I was stuck in the ground. Probably it. Will try.

Comment: are you using the proper tools (pick for stone,...)

Comment: I notice you ask if you're using an unstable build, but you don't tell us what build you're using. Could you?

Comment: @ratchetfreak Yes. I successfully removed the block, but no drop.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I don't know how to tell that, but I just tested Batophobia's suggestion and it worked.

Comment: @AnnonomusPerson if you hit a block long enough with anything it will break eventually but that doesn't guarantee a drop

Comment: @AnnonomusPerson I have posted the answer.  Perhaps a friendly mod might come along now and clean up the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When starting a new server, there is a property in `server.properties` called `spawn-protection`.  On a standard server, the only users that can modify blocks within this region are ops.

You can make yourself an op by running this command on the server `op playername`.  Alternatively, you can edit the `ops.txt` file directly and add your username to the list.

For more information about server properties, see [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Server.properties).

Answer (score 0):

You probably disabled block drops in `server.properties` or something.

Comment: Please use real words.

Comment: There is no option like that. I have worked with non-spigot servers plenty of times.

Comment: There is a doTileDrops gamerule, although it's not in server.properties.