# Why do I never receive blocks when mining?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I work in Vanilla style Minecraft in version 1.8.4 and I am playing a survival style map with cheats ON. I am POSITIVE that I am on game-mode 0 and after switching back from creative to survival; I am unable to receive the block after mining it. I tried ALL types of tools and NONE of them work!

I rebooted and ran Minecraft setup wizard repair on the files. I cant have a virus because I have Norton. My mouse settings are fine and the problem only appears on the one server that I play on. I have a house, a horse named Shadow and a dog named Gandalf that are at stake!

Comment: Try the gamerule doTileDrop and set it to true. If that doesn't work I may have another idea.

Comment: I am able to mine blocks on other servers of mine just fine.

Comment: `I cant have a virus because I have Norton.` Norton _is_ a virus.

Comment: Darn I guess I could have put that in as a answer... Oh and gamerules are only related to the current world.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just a thought, but you might want to ask a server admin to do

```
/gamerule doTileDrops true
```

Comment: I own the server and it is in single player.

Comment: OMG THANK YOU ALL SOOOOO MUCH! I TRIED THE COMMAND AND IT FIXED IT!

Comment: @ISKRVII_ If this fixed the issue, remember to mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 6):

It could possibly be a server issue.

> When starting a new server, there is a property in server.properties called spawn-protection. On a standard server, the only users that can modify blocks within this region are ops.
>
> You can make yourself an op by running this command on the server op playername. Alternatively, you can edit the ops.txt file directly and add your username to the list.

Refer to this previous [Question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/132144/why-dont-mined-blocks-show-up-in-my-inventory-on-my-spigot-server)

Comment: Thanks but what is OP? I know im sort of a noob :(

Comment: An 'operator'. Basically another word for an admin/moderator :) @ISKRVII_

Comment: Spawn protection prevents breaking of blocks altogether. If spawn protection was the issue, this would be an "I can't break blocks" issue.